# Unmarshal multiple XML items

Tags: xml, go

I am trying to unmarshal multiple items contained in nodes with an identical structure for further processing, but don't seem to be able to access the data and I am not sure why. The XML data is structured in the following form (I am trying to access all of the `Item`'s:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
<datainfo>
  <origin>NOAA/NOS/CO-OPS</origin>
  <producttype> Annual Tide Prediction </producttype>
  <IntervalType>High/Low Tide Predictions</IntervalType>
  <data>
    <item>
      <date>2015/12/31</date>
      <day>Thu</day>
      <time>03:21 AM</time>
      <predictions_in_ft>5.3</predictions_in_ft>
      <predictions_in_cm>162</predictions_in_cm>
      <highlow>H</highlow>
    </item>
    <item>
      <date>2015/12/31</date>
      <day>Thu</day>
      <time>09:24 AM</time>
      <predictions_in_ft>2.4</predictions_in_ft>
      <predictions_in_cm>73</predictions_in_cm>
      <highlow>L</highlow>
    </item>
  </data>
</datainfo>
```

My code is:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

// TideData stores a series of tide predictions
type TideData struct {
    Tides []Tide `xml:"data>item"`
}

// Tide stores a single tide prediction
type Tide struct {
    Date         string  `xml:"date"`
    Day          string  `xml:"day"`
    Time         string  `xml:"time"`
    PredictionFt float64 `xml:"predictions_in_ft"`
    PredictionCm float64 `xml:"predictions_in_cm"`
    HighLow      string  `xml:"highlow"`
}

func (t Tide) String() string {
    return t.Date + " " + t.Day + " " + t.Time + " " + t.HighLow
}

func main() {
    xmlFile, err := os.Open("9414275 Annual.xml")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error opening file:", err)
        return
    }
    defer xmlFile.Close()

    b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(xmlFile)

    var tides TideData
    xml.Unmarshal(b, &tides)

    fmt.Println(tides)
    for _, datum := range tides.Tides {
        fmt.Printf("\t%s\n", datum)
    }
}
```

When run the output is empty, which leads me to think that the data is not unmarshalled. Output is:

```
{[]}
```

Comment: What is the error returned from xml.Unmarshal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are ignoring the error return from `xml.Unmarshal`.  By [slightly modifying your program](http://play.golang.org/p/EwcBAGnEPJ), we can see what is going on:

```
xml: encoding "ISO-8859-1" declared but Decoder.CharsetReader is nil
```

And [poking around in the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Decoder), we find that by default the package only supports XML encoded in UTF-8:

```
    // CharsetReader, if non-nil, defines a function to generate
    // charset-conversion readers, converting from the provided
    // non-UTF-8 charset into UTF-8. If CharsetReader is nil or
    // returns an error, parsing stops with an error. One of the
    // the CharsetReader's result values must be non-nil.
    CharsetReader func(charset string, input io.Reader) (io.Reader, error)
```

So it seems you need to provide your own character set conversion routine.  You can inject it by modifying your code something like this:

```
decoder := xml.NewDecoder(xmlFile)
decoder.CharsetReader = makeCharsetReader
err := decoder.Decode(&tides)
```

(note that we're now decoding from an `io.Reader` rather than a byte array now, so the `ReadAll` logic can be removed).  The [`golang.org/x/text/encoding` family of packages](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/encoding) might help you in implementing your `makeCharsetReader` function.  Something like this might work:

```
import "golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap"

func makeCharsetReader(charset string, input io.Reader) (io.Reader, error) {
    if charset == "ISO-8859-1" {
        // Windows-1252 is a superset of ISO-8859-1, so should do here
        return charmap.Windows1252.NewDecoder().Reader(input), nil
    }
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("Unknown charset: %s", charset)
}
```

You should then be able to decode the XML.